# Retrieve TextInput Value after Button Click - onSubmitEditing React-Native

Tags: react-native

I need to set & retrieve the value for a TextInput field after I click a TouchableHighlight/Button (doesn't matter just need the value) but I'm doing something wrong and don't understand what I should do to correct this.

If someone could chime in that would be really sweet.

My React-Native code looks like this right now:

```
export default function TabOneScreen() {

  const [recipientEmail, setRecipientEmail] = useState("");

  async function getUserList() {

    var headers = 
    { 
      headers: 
      { 
          "Accept" : "*/*",
          "Connection": "keep-alive",
          "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
          "Host": subdomain + ".conveyor.cloud"
      }
    };

    var response = await axios.get('https://' + subdomain + '.conveyor.cloud/Home/GetUserData/?q=' + recipientEmail, headers)

    setMatchingUsers(response.data);
    console.log(matchingUsers);
    return response.data; 
  }

  return (
     <TextInput 
       placeholder='Enter Recipient Email or Name' 
       onSubmitEditing={(e) => setRecipientEmail(e.nativeEvent.text)}> 
     </TextInput>
     <TouchableHighlight onPress={getUserList}>
        <Text>Submit</Text>
     </TouchableHighlight>
  );

}
```

I need the value of the TextInput to be accessible in the `getUserList` function.
I've tried referencing the `recipientEmail` variable within `getUserList` but to no avail...

Please help.

I tried setting and getting a TextInput value in the onSubmitEditing property but the way I'm doing it is somehow incorrect. I was expecting that my reference to `recipientEmail` would properly get the value of what was inputted into the TextInput.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the good property from your `TextInput`. It should be this one used:

```
<TextInput 
    placeholder='Enter Recipient Email or Name' 
    onChangeText={setRecipientEmail}
    value={recipientEmail}
/>
```